Fix high DPC latency for stornvme.sys (NVM Express controller)
I have a PC with Windows 11 (I had windows 10 and updated when it came out the 11) and it frequently get unusable because of very long freezes. After investigating for a while it seems that the problem is stornvme.sys driver for NVM Express Controller.
I tested with LatencyMon and that has very high DPC counts and very high Total Execution.
From Task manager I see all the time high CPU usage from "System interrupts".
I tried to update the driver but it seems the one I have is the latest (from 2006?) but I'm not sure.
I wanted to try update the BIOS but it's not available for my notebook with Windows 11 (only Windows 10 uff!). It seems the fault is due to stupid Windows 11 but I don't want to go back to Windows 10 because it's a big mess with all the files.
Any idea?
